# Google Chrome claims TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN are incompatible applications

Tags: google-chrome, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

Starting with Google Chrome 69 the Chrome browser identifies TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN as incompatible applications (after a crash) as Chrome seems to head towards to disallow dlls to be injected into the Chrome browser: "Update or remove incompatible applications. This application could prevent Chrome from running properly." Listing TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN.

[image: Update or remove incompatible applications. This application could prevent Chrome from running properly]

Where can I find some details about this behaviour. How to fix this and get rid of this warning and continue to use TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN are Windows Shell extensions and are loaded automatically as soon as a Windows Shell component is loaded (e.g., for the open save dialog in Chrome).

In order to get around this, go to Settings and check "Show overlays and context menu only in explorer":

[image: Settings Dialog]

This will prevent Chrome from loading the full TortoiseGit/TortoiseSVN shell extension.

According to https://superuser.com/a/1357766/353744 this warning only occurs after a crash of Chrome.